# Spring Boot no reconoce un Objeto enviado desde http de angular4

Tags: spring-boot, angular5

Estoy intentando ejecutar una llamada post desde una aplicacion angular hacia una api desarrollada con Spring boot. Lo que sucede es que no me realiza el bind entre el objeto que envio y el que se espera como parametro. Si lo ejecuto desde postman enviando los parametros como form-data o urlencoded funciona bien, pero no desde la aplicacion.

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
UserById(param: Object): any {
console.log(JSON.stringify(param));
return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/userbyid', JSON.stringify(param), this.opciones()).pipe(
  map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
  }),
);
```

}

Probe enviar el objeto como JSON como se ve en el cofigo y sin parsear y de ninguna de las dos formas funciona. Un ejemplo de JSON que envio es:

```
{"User":"leonardo_alvarez","User2":"Usuario2"}
```

EL codigo de la API es el siguiente:

```
public class userObj {

    private String user;
    private String user2;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUser2() {
        return user2;
    }

    public void setUser2(String user2) {
        this.user2 = user2;
    }
}

@Autowired
private REL_UserRepository rel_userRepository;
@PostMapping(path = "/userbyid")
public @ResponseBody List<REL_User> getUser (userObj User){
    return rel_userRepository.findByUserid(User.getUser());
}
```

Alguien sabe que puede estar ocacionando esto?

Comment: En el código de Angular tienes `this._http`... ¿de qué clase es ese campo, `Http` o `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 0):

Por el código que has adjuntado, parece que necesitas añadir tres detalles:

1. Añadir un constructor por defecto que sea capaz de instanciar un objeto sin ningún parámetro.
2. Añadir la anotación `@RequestBody` en el parametro `userObj User`
3. En el la anotación de PostMapping añade que el endpoint consume un json de la siguiente forma: `@PostMapping(path = "/userbyid", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`.

Además a la hora de lanzar la petición al servicio indica en el header de la petición que el `Content-Type` es un `application/json`.

De todas formas puedes consultar este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291933/requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations-in-spring) si tienes alguna otra duda sobre la anotación `RequestBody`

Comment: Ya probe agregando la anotacion RequestBody, pero me tira un error que dice que el Media Type no es compatible.